# Bootstrap - columns with spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create four columns in a row using bootstrap. There should be some spacing between columns. please check the image. can someone tell me how to create a page like seen in the image?
[image: details]

Answer (score 1):

Anoted in the comments below, your desired box width of 344px, 4*344=1376, this doesnt fit into the bootstrap grid system for smaller sizes, so will wrap, as such you will need to use e.g:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9324/)

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
}
.wrapper div {
    display:inline-block;
    background:lightblue;
    margin:5px;
    height:200px;
    width:344px;
}
```

Otherwise the bootstrap way:

### [Demo Field](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9323/)

Given the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use the CSS (should be tidied)

```
[class*=col] div {
    background:lightblue;
    margin:5px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: thanks.  I want to use height:170px and width:344px. if i use width:344px, all div is wrapped and displayed as single div. if i use width:100%, columns are seperated.

Comment: 4*344=1376, this doesnt fit into the bootstrap grid system for smaller sizes, so will wrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: New example provided above- please note ideally you should list all your constraints in the question to ensure provided answers are as appropriate as possible

Comment: ok. In this case i can't use width:344px. is there any other wap to use width 344px.

Comment: ok. how to display image in left and date in right inside <div>. i used float:left. if i display <p>... </p> after image, the text inside <p>  is not displayed next line.

Comment: @Ajaii - you should open a new question

Answer (score 1):

DEMO **UPDATED** bootply: http://www.bootply.com/T8BDlFLpRD

You can use this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

      </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

      </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

      </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

      </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" class="img-responsive">

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{ 
  background:orange; 
}
.col-md-3{
  height:200px;
  padding-top:25px;
}
```

Comment: In your code, the second row is displayed without any space.

Comment: Space above the 2nd row?

Comment: In my screen space is there.. :(

Comment: If you want to add more space to the second row you can give margin top to it.

Comment: how to reduce the space between columns?

Comment: Reduce the padding to 10px or less.. and if you want the whole content to be at the center use a container..thats it..do you want me to change the bootply?

Comment: Bootply updated. Link in answer. Please check. @Ajaii

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">block 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">block 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">block 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">block 4</div>
</div>
```

Inside each block, you can put your column content

Comment: Alternatively, if that doesn't provide enough of a gutter, each line could be `class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"`

Comment: Do I have to include the above inside a <div class="container> or <div class=3container-fluid>.  I want to use height:170px and width:344px.  if i use width:344px, all div is wrapped and displayed as single div.