# Set 30px gutter with 4 Bootstrap-3 Cols @270

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've spent considerable time researching and trying various methods to achieve the desired outcome. The most helpful post [Bootstrap - columns with spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247284/bootstrap-columns-with-spacing) got me almost all the way there.

Given this 4-col comp at 1170px wide [image: 4 column 1170px wide], with each of the four columns set to 270px wide with a 30px gutter, I can't seem to arrange Bootstrap 3 to force the 30px wide gutters so that the left and right outer columns left-align and right-align respectively, with equal gutters between them.

Here's what I ended up with: [image: Output of following code]

CODE BLOCK

```
  <!-- Four Services Columns -->
  <div class="services-wrap container">
    <div class="services-wrap row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /. services-wrap -->
```

CSS

```
.services-outer {}
.services-wrap.row {
    margin: 0;
}
.services-wrap.container {
    padding:0;
}
.services-wrap .col-md-3 {
    padding:0;
}
```

Question: given that (4 x 270) + (3 x 30) = 1170, why doesn't Bootstrap equally space the columns and, how do I do so without impacting the responsive when it collapses?

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/aDoQyUK5aR) Thanks @T30!

Comment: You can set up a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) helping users reproduce the problem

Comment: Sorry. Didn't think of that. Doing it now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think to do this is pad each column by 15px and extend the row out like so:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 .service-row {
  margin: 0 -30px;
}
.service {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row service-row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 service">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 service">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 service">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 service">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/270x310" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @LincolnTosi! I deployed your suggestions, but end up with this: http://steep-pop.livestyle.io/

Comment: Lincoln, solved it. Removed the outer div.container and viola... perfect alignment. Thank you!